# bash скрипт перебора директорий

Tags: linux, bash, for

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно использовать for в bash.
У меня есть 2 папки foo  и bar, я пишу скрипт:

```
#/bin/bash

paths=(foo bar)

for i in "${paths}"
        do
                echo "${i}"
        done
```

и получаю в ответ :

```
foo
```

Вопрос где bar?

Comment: `paths=(foo bar); for i in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done` или `paths="foo bar"; for i in $paths; do echo "${i}"; done`

Comment: Так работает спасибо!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
paths=(foo bar); for i in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done
```

`"${paths[@]}"` возвращает каждый элемент массива как отдельную строку.

В вашем конкретном примере можно также воспользоваться более простым подходом (только если в элементах массива нет пробелов):

```
paths="foo bar"; for i in $paths; do echo "${i}"; done
```

**Дополнительная информация**

При работе с массивами можно использовать следующие конструкции:

```
${arr[*]}         # Все элементы массива
${!arr[*]}        # Все индексы в массиве
${#arr[*]}        # Количество элементов в массиве
${#arr[0]}        # Длина первого элемента (элемента с нулевым индексом)
```